# Return all indices of matching elements in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array as:
`["Front", "Front", "Back", "Back", "Side", Side]`

What I need to do is return the indices for all matching occurrences of a particular string. For example, if inputting: `"Front"` it should return `[0,1]`, input `"Side"`, should return `[4,5]` and `"Back"` would return `[2,3]`

How can this be accomplished in Java efficiently?

Comment: There is not other way more efficient than looping it once and getting its indexes when it found using `equals()` which is O(n).

Comment: Note that it also depends on the characteristics of the input array itself. For example, if all the equal words are contiguous, or better yet, sorted, there would be ways to optimize. If it's random, then O(n) is your only choice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    String inPut="Side";

    String data [] = {"Front", "Front", "Back", "Back", "Side", "Side"};

    ArrayList positions=new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0;i<data.length;i++)
    {
        if(inPut.equals(data[i]))
        {
            positions.add(i);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(positions);
}
```

output

```
[4, 5]
```

Try with changed inputs

Comment: Use a linked list instead to avoid re-allocation maybe? Otherwise, good stuff.